# dependent or independent probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have 80 professors:
25 engineers
15 computer science
35 math
5 stats

What is Pc(D)=P(D|C), where the experiment is to choose 6 professors at random and

```
event C={all the stats prof are chosen}
event D={no math professors chosen}
```

is this independent or dependent? I want to say dependent because if you choose all the stats professors then the probability of the event D will be dependent on the fact that there are -5 stats professors gone + any other professors since you have to choose 6). Is that right or is it independent?

if it is dependent, is my math correct?

```
P(C)=((5 choose 5)*(75 choose 1))/(80 choose 6)
P(D)=(45 choose 6)/(80 choose 6)
```

these events are dependent so:

```
Pc(D)=P(D|C)=P(D intersection C)/P(C) 
where P(D intersection C)=P(D)*P(C|D) 
so Pc(D)=(P(D)*P(C|D))/P(C)

so we he have (((45 choose 6)/(80 choose 6)) * (40/75))) /(((5 choose 5)*(75 choose 1))/(80 choose 6))
                           P(D)              *  P(C|D)   /             P(C)
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If no math profs are chosen, the chance of getting all of the stats profs goes up, so the events cannot be independent.

Comment: but aren't we trying to find the probability of event D based on C having already happened? But i guess what you are saying works the other way around.

Comment: This flows both ways; the occurrence of one event affects the probability of the other.

Comment: could you check my math then? It is based on dependence P(D intersection C)=P(D)*P(C|D) instead of P(D intersection C)=P(D)*P(C)